# Export GPS coordinates from a bunch of Google Maps markers?

Tags: google-maps, gps, export, coordinates

so if you search for "monuments" in Google Maps, you'll get all the pointers for any monument in a city.
You can then right click on any of them and see the GPS coordinates for that specific pointer, but it's any way to get the GPS coordinates of all pointers at once?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do a nearby search using the `google.maps.places.PlacesService` you get as a result an array containing all the data.

In [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) from the official documentation the data is contained in the array `results` in the `callback` function. To view all locations:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results[i].geometry.location));
    }
```

.